# Процедура, которая показывает сегодняшний день недели

Tags: sql-server

Как создать процедуру, которая показывает сегодняшний день недели?

Answer (score 2):

зачем для этого процедура (их обычно пишут когда нужно выполнить много sql запросов и т.д на сервере), попробуйте так если это SQL Server 2005/2008 :

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw,GETDATE());
SELECT DATEPART(dw,GETDATE());
```

или если это Mysql :

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(NOW());
```

только учтите эти функции выводят первый день недели воскресенье